# Number of times one can renew "carte de sejour" in France as a Visitor

Tags: france, resident-permit, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen currently staying in France since 1 year with a "visitor" visa without employment. See the link http://www.consulfrance-losangeles.org/spip.php?article799

I also renewed my visa for 1 more year, that is, now I have the "carte de sejour" valid for another one year.

My question is how many times can I renew my carte de sejour. I actually want to stay in France for 4 more years. Will it be possible to renew my carte de sejour 4 times (i.e a total of 6 years in France), once at the end of each year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hard limit, but you have to renew the permit every year. This means that the authorities will reevaluate whether you meet the requirements and could refuse to renew it. If you still have sufficient resources and your situation hasn't changed, it can be renewed indefinitely (although at some point you would also qualify for some other status or even citizenship, if you were so inclined).

Comment: Could you please give me a reference of what you say. I know that this will be time consuming for you but still I insist to have some reference like website links or pdf.

Comment: @BiswarupRay The main reference would be [service-public.fr](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F302) and especially the bit where it says the permit is "renouvelable". I would not expect to find a source spelling it out more explicitly but that's how it works in France in general and if there was a limit, it would be stated there.